# Virtualtreeview dragNdrop

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, virtualtreeview

How to copy between two virtualtreeview to copy all columns, not just the first one?

before copy:

[image]

after copy:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the current code you have for the copying part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree control holds no data. It doesn't contain the column data you want to show, so *it* has no way of copying it. Rather, when the tree control wants to display data for any cell, it asks your program what to display by triggering the `OnCellText` event. It displays whatever your program tells it to.

If your copied-to control isn't displaying what you want, then it's because your `OnCellText` event handler for that control isn't giving it the necessary data.

When you copy a node, it's your responsibility to ensure that the information associated with the source node gets stored somewhere such that the destination control's `OnCellText` event knows where to find it for the destination node. There are any number of ways to do that. It all depends on how you're copying the node in the first place, and how you're representing your underlying data structure that the `OnCellText` event uses. Within those constraints, you can do it any way you want.